# Как проверить пустой ли итератор в java?

Tags: java, итераторы

У меня есть итератор (не важно откуда он взялся, я о нем ничего не знаю)

Мне необходимо определить пустой ли он.
Т.е. если я делаю

```
System.out.println(iter.getClass());
```

мне выводится `class java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator`

как я могу в коде определять, пуст ли итератор?
Хотелось бы вроде

```
if (iter.пустой)
{
System.out.println("итератор пуст");
}
```

PS
вопрос не про `iter.hasNext();`

Comment: @Миша Перминов: Вот вам статья по теме: http://codechaos.me/?p=22

Comment: Объясните смысл термина *итератор пустой* - я вот если честно не понимаю, смысл этого словосочетания

Comment: iter.hasNext()как раз и указывает, пуст ли итератор. Другого способа нет.

Answer (score 3):

Термин "пустой итератор" не совсем корректен. Сам по себе итератор — это указатель на элемент коллекции, который может передвигаться вперед по коллекции и знает, когда коллекция закончилась. Если вы хотите проверить, что *коллекция* пуста, тогда нужно взять у нее итератор и вызвать метод `hasNext()` у итератора. Если метод вернет `false`, значит, больше элементов нет, т.е. коллекция пуста. Важным условием является то, что `hasNext()` должен вызываться *сразу*, без (или до) итерации по коллекции.

Comment: Ответ конечно правильный, но советовать проверять пустоту коллекции вызовом у итератора `hasNext()`, по-моему, уже перебор) Всё-таки не зря у интерфейса Collection есть метод `isEmpty()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#isEmpty()

Comment: @Vartlok я лишь пытался предположить, что автор вопроса подразумевал под "пустым итератором".